# Mysql Visualization Tools

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, visualization

Does anyone know a good (preferably open source and cross platform) tool to allow simple visualization of mysql databases?  I just need a tool I can quickly point at a database and it'll show basic table structure and field types, etc.  Nothing too advanced or crazy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) runs on Windows and Linux. The commercial version will let you reverse engineer and edit the stucture of a live database, with the free one you have first to dump the structure to a file. Its ancestor [DBDesigner](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) is a bit older, but doesn't have this limitation. Windows and Linux too.

If these two are overkill you may try with [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), the descendant of MySQLFront. It runs on Windows only, but there is an alpha version running on Java.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is well done, it replaces MySQL GUI Tools

Comment: The free one apparently now lets you reverse engineer a database. It also runs on mac. :-)

Comment: +1 HeidiSQL. Simple and easy to use. Plus has SSH tunneling.Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

I really like [Sqlyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) on Windows. It is (technically) open source, but not cross-platform. (Scroll down to "community edition")

If your requirements are open source, simple, and cross-platform, hav eyou considered setting up a website with [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net)?

Comment: I do that already.  I generally set up apache virtual hosts for dev sites and they all use a single mysql instance which is managed via phpmyadmin.  Only problem is phpmyadmin is slow and clunky, I was looking for something client side, lightweight, and more of a graphical view of the tables.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

mysql-administrator

Answer (score 2):

There's also MySQL Workbench.  It's more for design, but would do what you ask.  There's a free version which is a little crippled and I think it might be Windows only.

EDIT:  There is a Linux version.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html

Answer (score 1):

Sqlyog community should be fine