# MySQL Table Structure Visualization?

Tags: mysql, database, visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql Visualization Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363658/mysql-visualization-tools)

Is there an online tool or an app that can create a graph or an image of an imported database that shows the relationship between the tables inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dbForge does this as well, so it seems you have lots of options.

Link: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html

Answer (score 3):

If an app is okay: [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

Comment: I liked that tool in Workbench, but since some time it crahshes for me. Latest one I tried is 6.3.10.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [DB Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/features/index.jsp?feature=9)